# Response body empty API

Tags: flutter, dart

My response.body return empty like this: Response.body: []
It was supposed to return the param like Response.body:["CodVenda":4057}]

```
 static Future<List<Produto>> iniciaVenda(codVenda) async {
  var url = 'http://192.168.0.112:4343/inicia_venda.php';

  Map<String, String> headers = {};
  final params = {"CodVenda": codVenda};
  print("> Params: $params");
  print("> Pedido Post POST: $url");

  final response = await http.post(url, body: params, headers: headers);

  print('Response status: ${response.statusCode}');
  print('Response body: ${response.body}');

  List list = convert.json.decode(response.body);

  final produtos =
      list.map<Produto>((map) => Produto.fromJson(map)).toList();

  var retornoResponse = false;
```

I get the data from a API and then I wanted to start the sell but it returns empty.
Could it be a problem in API?

Comment: `response.body` contains the response string of the HTTP call. If the response is the JSON of an empty list, then that's what your API returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, you need to pass body data with JSON encoded. That may be the main problem.

```
     final response = await http.post(url, body: jsonEncode(params), headers: headers);
```

You can read more from the [official document](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/send-data).